# Why is my javascript for loop outputting nothing

Tags: javascript

when I use the code below it outputs nothing to the screen.

I have global array called `tasks[]` and this is the function I am trying to run:

```
function addTask() {
'use strict';

var task = document.getElementById('task');
var outputTask = document.getElementById('taskOutput');
var outputList = document.getElementById('outputList');

var taskMessage = '';

if (task.value) {
    tasks[tasks.length] = task;
    taskMessage = 'You have ' + tasks.length + ' task(s) in your to-do list.';

    if(output.textContent !== undefined) {
        outputTask.textContent = taskMessage;   
    } else {
        outputTask.innerText = taskMessage;
    }


    for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i <= count; i++) {
        var listItem = document.createElement('h3');
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(tasks[i]);
        listItem.appendChild(textNode);
        outputList.appendChild(listItem);
    }

}// End task.value IF.
return false;
}// end addTask() function
```

Here's the HTML that the javascript is accessing. When I enter a value into the task input field and press submit, I am expecting output to the screen inside the outputList div as H3's.

```
    <form id="theForm" name="theForm" />
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter the starting and ending dates of the task</legend>
<label for="start">Start</label>
<input type="text" name="start" id="start" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY or Today" required />

<label for="end">End</label>
<input type="text" name="end" id="end" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required />
</fieldset>
<fieldset><legend>Enter a Task For This Time Period</legend>
<div>
<label for="task">Task</label>
<input type="text" name="task" id="task" required />
</div>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Add It!" id="submit" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
<div id="taskOutput"></div>
<div id="outputList"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `task.value` is defined?

Comment: Is the code you expect to cause output being run? What are the values of the variables used by that code? Are they what you expect? For every answer that is "no", ask "why?". Now you have started to debug.

Comment: Make sure the following line evalutes as expected
"if (task.value)" and
"count = tasks.length;"

Comment: yes, task.value is defined by text input @SomeKitens.

Comment: why am I getting a down vote? Because you couldn't answer the question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are looping beyond the last item in the array.

Change this:

```
for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i <= count; i++) {
```

to:

```
for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
```

Comment: wow thank you! Seems to be working. Now I have to figure out why it's doubling the items when I press submit